# OpenSplice DDS: Publish, until some timeout

Tags: c++, synchronous, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I'm learning every day more about dds, so my question my sound weird. I hope it makes sense.

One of the requirements of some dds wrapper I'm writing, is that it times out after some timeout period if it fails to write. **My question:** How can I do that?

On [Prism Tech's website's tutorial](http://download.prismtech.com/docs/Vortex/html/ospl/DDSTutorial/readandwrite.html), there's explanation on how to use a `WaitSet` to block a read operation, but what about write?

Here's some code including the question:

```
dds::domain::DomainParticipant dp(0);
dds::topic::Topic<MyType> topic(dp, "MyTopic");
dds::pub::Publisher pub(dp);
dds::pub::DataWriter<MyType> dw(pub, topic);

MyType t;
dw.write(t); //how can I make this block for 5 seconds (tops), and then throw an error on failure?
```

I noticed there exists a function in the API [`DataWriter::wait_for_acknowledgements(int timeout)`](http://dev.opensplice.org/releases/downloads/docs/isocpp/html/classdds_1_1pub_1_1_data_writer.html#aaa79bd56ae4e8980a39f8c8a331df4b7), but this seems to be bound to the `DataWriter` object, not to the specific call of writing. Can I bind it with the call above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is configured in QoS, cf RELIABILITY, field "max_blocking_time".  How you set this value will depend on the vendor's implementation.  Generally you get the current QoS, update the field, write the QoS back.  Keep in mind that certain QoS policies must be set before something else happens.  Reliability is "Before Enable" (at least in the implementation I'm most familiar with), which means you need to create the data-writer disabled, update the QoS, then enable the writer.

If QoS can be set outside the application (via XML for example), then you can set the policy easily.  Otherwise, you need to do it in code.

From the spec:

*The value of the max_blocking_time indicates the maximum time the operation DataWriter::write is allowed to block if the DataWriter does not have space to store the value written. The default max_blocking_time=100ms.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this solution soon and report. I suppose after this period it throws an error, that I can catch and handle, right?

Comment: Depends on the implementation and language, whether it is a DDS_RETCODE_TIMEOUT, a RETCODE_TIMEOUT, a dds::core::TimeoutError, a TimeoutException, ... etc.  Usually this is a resource constraint rather than a communications issue (history not deep enough, memory is exhausted for this participant, etc).